# Angular routing in the same page

Tags: angular

I want to use angular routing in the same page with all the same components whether it is /frontpage or /frontpage/param1/param2/param3. But just updating my children component with param1 param2 param3 parameters..

I have a frontpage component which has a bunch of children (and their children) components.

I was building in a way that there was no URL change and it was just /frontpage but I want to add my queries and parameters into my url that updates my children.

But I'm not really understanding how to do this.

app.routing.ts

```
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'frontpage',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: '404',
    component: P404Component,
    data: {
      title: 'Page 404'
    }
  },
{
    path: '', // honestly I just realized this was here lol. I can probably take this out right? lol.. It was part of the base I am using.
    component: DefaultLayoutComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Home'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'frontpage',
        loadChildren: () => import(etcetc).then(m => m.FrontpageModule)
      },
```

frontpage-routing.module.ts

```
  {
    path: '',
    component: FrontpageComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Frontpage'
    },
  },
```

Where do I add the /:param1/:param2/:param3 ??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are no optional params in routing - just write second route. If for some strange reason you need a lot of children there - extract it to some variable and pass inside of each. Routes are just provided config via token, no big deal.

```
  const toneOfChildren = [...];
  {
    path: '',
    component: FrontpageComponent,
    children: toneOfChildren  
  },
  {
    path: ':param1/:param2/:param3',
    component: FrontpageComponent,
    children: toneOfChildren  
  },
```

And in `FrontpageComponent` just subscribe to params and see if they are here or not.

Comment: Thanks! Yea I had just written multiple routes

Comment: So I was doing it like this.. But if I want to set default params for param1,2,3 instead of path '', how would I do this? so if I want to go to frontpage/1/2/3 on load instead of frontpage..

```
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'frontpage/1/2/3',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },


  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'dashboard/Global/all/all', }

```
is what I did

Comment: Yeah, if it always should have params - do redirect.

Comment: I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.. but when I'm trying to make a "default" route, it is causing me to redirect to that page whenever I am reloading..